# C++ virtual method raises EXC_BAD_ACCESS (only if called by Objective-C++)

Tags: c++, inheritance, clang, abstract-class, virtual-functions

I have the following things as part of a very large codebase:

```
class FooObserver {
public:
     virtual void FooObjectChanged() = 0;
};

class MainStuff :  public FooObserver {
public:
    /* ... */
    void FooObjectChanged();
    void doSomething();
};

void MainStuff::doSomething() {    
    this->FooObjectChanged();
    FooObserver *o = this;
    o->FooObjectChanged();
}

void MainStuff::FooObjectChanged() {
    std::cout << "object changed\n";
}
```

My understanding of the C++ standard is that this is valid code and `FooObjectChanged()` would be called twice without any error when `doSomething()` runs.

But my application fails on the second call. (with segfault, or more precisely `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on iOS)

Another compiler issue is that, If I remove `MainStuff::FooObjectChanged()` (both the body and its declaration), I would expect the linker to fail with complaints about an abstract class. But compiler does not fail. It links and then the program crashes on the first call to the virtual function with

```
libc++abi.dylib: Pure virtual function called!
```

What is going on? What may cause these problems? `FooObserver` is not a base class of anything else, only of `MainStuff`.

Comment: Construction function shall not be a pure virtual function! And it shall not be a virtual function either!

Comment: You mean constructor? That can't even be virtual in C++ so none of them are in this application.

Comment: Do you call it *from* a constructor, directly or indirectly? Also, `make clean` and see if it keeps crashing.

Comment: It's not called from a constructor. But "make clean" seems to be in the right direction, I am still trying to make sure but it seems that XCode messed up something with the build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be some problem with XCode. For some reason it stopped recompiling some of the source files. After removing everything from the DerivedData folder and restarting XCode the code compiles, links and runs as I expect.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if there is any other pure virtual function inherited from some other base class in `MainStuff` and you didn't override in `MainStuff`
2. Check doSomething is called on a valid object that is alive and within scope (not destroyed while `MainStuff::doSomething()` has been called and in processing)

Comment: All the other pure virtual functions are overridden in MainStuff, and I didn't find any problems using them. MainStuff is alive and within scope.

Comment: @pramparam then try recompiling the whole code, should be ok, don't see any problem from the code snippet that you posted

Comment: The #1 does not even make sense; any sane compiler will raise compile-error if a single "pure virtual function" is not implemented/defined (like: can't construct abstract-class).

Answer (score 0):

I just meet similar issue, where I had multiple (2 or more) C++ **private-Classes** (i.e. where Class has no Header), and all with exact same name, but *defined* in different `.mm` files; **each used as template-argument** (in same `.mm` file, where it was defined) for `std::shared_ptr` smart-pointer.

Sometimes when calling one class's `virtual` method (using smart-pointer's `->` operator), **`Clang` decided to use another class's `vtable`** (which's header was NOT even ever included), resulting in binary that calls wrong method-address (and that wrong-method accessed fields, which do simply not exist in class, a.k.a. SIGSEG or BAD_ACCESS).

I was shocked, because private-class is a common C++ approach, but changing each private Class's name (or at least, those used in `.mm` files's templates-args), did fix Objective-C++'s (or rather Clang's) issue.